# access and change color of pixels based on another image - opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image in two different formats. one is BGR and the other is black and white (there is only black and white, no gray colored pixels). Its the same exact image (same size and pixels). I want to find all the white pixels in the black and white image, mark them down and then find the exact same pixels in the BGR image (obviously they are colored in the BGR image) and color them black.
I tried it but the thing is the black and white image has 1 channel and the BGR one has 3 channels so i failed...
i am using opencv in c++
thanks for your help! :)

```
for(int y=0;y<inputImage.rows;y++){
    for(int x=0;x<inputImage.cols;x++){
        Vec3b color = inputImage.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
        if(blackWhite.at<uchar>(y,x) == 255){
            //cout << "found white pixel\n";
            color[0] = 0;
            color[1] = 0;
            color[2] = 0;
            inputImage.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = color;
        }
    }
}
```

inputImage is my BGR image and blackWhite is an image of same size with black and white pixels. both are Mat objects.
i want to go through the blackWhite image and whenever i find a white pixel, color the same pixel from the inputImage image in black color.

Comment: Your black and white image is a ready binary mask, just apply it to your BGR image with OpenCV's `bitwise_and` function.

Comment: Is the code you revealed above does not work? It is conceptually correct. From my experience you should be carefull with the .at function (template type, also this method with cv::Point).

Answer (score 0):

My strategy is to construct an array similar to your blackWhite image. This array will be zeros and ones and we'll multiply it with inputImage to get the desired output.

Currently, your blackWhite image looks something like (for example)

```
blackWhite = 255 255   0   0 ....
....
```

in pseudocode. If we transform this image to become

```
newArray  =    0   0   1   1 ....
 ....
```

You could then use [cv::multiply](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html)(newArray, inputImage) to get the desired output.

One way to directly transform your existing blackWhite image into newArray would be to perform y = (-1/255)*x + 1 on every pixel in blackWhite. You can accomplish this with [cv::Mat::convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d6/classcv_1_1Mat.html)(outputImage, 8, -1/255, 1)